# gap between QListWidget items/icons

Tags: python, pyside2

I would like to remove the gap between my QListWidget items in my textureIconChart QListWidget. It is populated with items set with pixmap icons. I am using QListWidget set to a QHBoxLayout, which is set to a QVBoxLayout.

[image]

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets,QtCore,QtGui
import shiboken2


class texture_replacer():

    def texture_linker_UI(self):        
        windowName = "name"
        if cmds.window(windowName,exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI(windowName, wnd = True)           
        pointer = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
        parent = shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(pointer),QtWidgets.QWidget)
        window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(parent)
        window.setObjectName(windowName)
        window.setWindowTitle(windowName)       
        window.setMinimumSize(450,650)
        window.setMaximumSize(600,400)
        mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        window.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(mainWidget)                                    
        self.textureIconChartLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        textureIconsLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()        
        self.textureIconChartLayout.addLayout(textureIconsLayout)
        verticalLayout.addLayout(self.textureIconChartLayout)       
        self.textureIconChart = QtWidgets.QListWidget()       
        self.textureIconChart.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListWidget.IconMode)
        self.textureIconChart.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)        
        self.textureIconChart.setDragEnabled(0)
        self.textureIconChart.setMaximumWidth(290)
        self.populateListWidget()                            
        textureIconsLayout.addWidget(self.textureIconChart)

        textureIconsLayout.setSpacing(0)
        textureIconsLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)


tr = texture_replacer()
tr.texture_linker_UI()
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: I included the picture that demonstrates the issue. I am just looking for the methods users use to fix the issue, not debugging any code.

Comment: I ask you for the code because I find it strange that you mention a QHBoxLayout in a QListWidget, it seems to me that you have implemented it in a particular way, so I ask you for a code. Do you have a problem in providing an MCVE?

Comment: I will try and provide some code, I just have to pull it out of the larger program and see if I can make it self contained.

Comment: Now I see that mentions the QHBoxLayout is irrelevant. Anyway, your code helps you understand, from what I understand you want to eliminate the space between icons, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Its just a small detail, but would like the icons to rest next to each other with no gap between them